# How to properly add an asynchronous validation to a reactive form?

Tags: angular

In an angular 13 app and following the official [guide](http://Following%20this%20guide%20I%20try%20to%20implement%20an%20asynchronous%20validation) I am trying to implement an asynchronous validation

Here the implementation

check-current-password.validator.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CheckCurrentPasswordValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.userService.verifyMatchWithCurrentPassword(control.value).pipe(
      map((value) => (value ? null : { passwordMatch: true })),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  constructor() {}

  verifyMatchWithCurrentPassword(password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(password === 'password').pipe(delay(5000));
  }
}
```

In the documentation it is not explicit how to add the new asynchronous validation to the form, so I am trying the following

```
editPasswordForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    currentPassword: [
      '',
      [
        Validators.required,
        this.checkCurrentPasswordValidator.validate(), // <-- async validation
      ],
    ],
    newPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    repeatNewPassword: ['', Validators.required],
  },
  { validators: newPasswordMatchValidator }
);
```

In validate I get the following error message

> TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
> check-current-password.validator.ts(15, 5): An argument for 'control'
> was not provided

Can you tell me how to properly add an asynchronous validation to a reactive form?

Thanks in advance

**Update 1**

In order to complete my responsibilities, I have taken another way of adding the asynchronous validator. All credit to this [post](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/how-to-add-async-validators-to-an-angular-reactive-form/)

In `user.service.ts` I added the next method

```
passwordValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return this.verifyMatchWithCurrentPassword(control.value).pipe(
      map((value) => (value ? null : { passwordMatch: true }))
    );
  };
}
```

In order the add the async validator to the form I add this

```
editPasswordForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    currentPassword: [
      '',
      {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        asyncValidators: [this.userService.passwordValidator()],
        updateOn: 'blur',
      },
    ],
    newPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    repeatNewPassword: ['', Validators.required],
  },
  { validators: newPasswordMatchValidator }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this:

```
editPasswordForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    currentPassword: [
      '',
      [
        Validators.required,
        this.checkCurrentPasswordValidator.validate(), // <-- async validation
      ],
    ],
    newPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    repeatNewPassword: ['', Validators.required],
  },
  { validators: newPasswordMatchValidator }
);
```

to

```
editPasswordForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    currentPassword: [
      '',
      [Validators.required],
      this.checkCurrentPasswordValidator.validate(),
    ],
    newPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    repeatNewPassword: ['', Validators.required],
  },
  { validators: newPasswordMatchValidator }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I get the same behavior. I have updated the question showing how I managed to make it work, but without success for the way described in the guide of angular 13